# Custom Polygon not drawing correctly

Tags: java, opengl, vector, polygon, vertices

I'm currently designing a custom polygon using OpenGL in Java. I have defined the vertices and double checked the vertices being correct. I've done a test and can see the correct design I want when displaying the **LINE**. But, when I display as **FILL** the cross like shape does **NOT** appear to be a cross lined shaped.

I've defined the vertices 1-16. 1 starting from the bottom of the design (See Image). I then called the vectors anti-clockwise. The imagine showing the Line is what I wanted to draw, have a look at the vertex dots to see how I coordinated it. The polygon is the only thing which is not showing correctly

**Screen Shots**

LINE:
[image: LINE]

DOT:
[image: DOT]

FILL:
[image: FILL]

**CODE**

```
// DECLARED VARIABLE
Vertex v1 = new Vertex(0.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f);

Vertex v2 = new Vertex(0.5f, -4.0f, 0.0f);
Vertex v3 = new Vertex(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
Vertex v4 = new Vertex(4.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
Vertex v5 = new Vertex(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Vertex v6 = new Vertex(4.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
Vertex v7 = new Vertex(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
Vertex v8 = new Vertex(0.5f, 4.0f, 0.0f);

Vertex v9 = new Vertex(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);

Vertex v10 = new Vertex(-0.5f, 4.0f, 0.0f);
Vertex v11 = new Vertex(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
Vertex v12 = new Vertex(-4.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
Vertex v13 = new Vertex(-5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Vertex v14 = new Vertex(-4.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
Vertex v15 = new Vertex(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
Vertex v16 = new Vertex(-0.5f, -4.0f, 0.0f);

 // Draw Vertices anti clockwise

GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_POLYGON); {

    v1.submit();
    v2.submit();
    v3.submit();
    v4.submit();
    v5.submit();
    v6.submit();
    v7.submit();
    v8.submit();
    v9.submit();
    v10.submit();
    v11.submit();
    v12.submit();
    v13.submit();
    v14.submit();
    v15.submit();
    v16.submit();

}

GL11.glEnd();
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me out. I'm sensing that I'm missing something out.

Comment: Thank you for the correction to my posts and thank you for the answer. Never realised that there was two type of polygons. Since the project is a very basic one, I have decided to scrap the East and West blades and connect up to North and South blades. Thank you!